# Merge/Span CheckBox in DataGridView WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am successfully merging text rows in my `DataGrid` view over the span of dynamic # of rows by doing this..

```
if (IsTheSameCellValue(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex))
{ 
    if (e.ColumnIndex != 1)
        e.Value = "";       
    e.FormattingApplied = true;
    e.CellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
}
```

and hiding the border in `cellPaint` event. But the same doesn't work for checkbox cell because `e.value=""` fails to work.

Whats the best way to merge/span checkbox type column over rows?

Comment: Removing borders is not merging the rows or cells as the contents will not be merged. I'm afraid you are wasting your time; DGV isn't supporting merg/span.

Comment: Yes, its the illusion of merging. What would be another/better way to achieve this in winforms without having to hide borders?

Comment: Beats me. You need to know what dgv-functionality you need: Input? validation? data-binding..?